# Processing filenames in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, filenames

I've written a function to strip double spaces out of my raw data files:

```
def fixDat(file):
    '''
    Removes extra spaces in the data files. Replaces original file with new
    and renames original to "...._original.dat".
    '''
    import os

    import re
    with open(file+'.dat', 'r') as infile:
        with open(file+'_fixed.dat', 'w') as outfile:
            lines = infile.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                fixed = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)
                outfile.write(fixed)

    os.rename(file+'.dat', file+'_original.dat')
    os.rename(file+'_fixed.dat', file+'.dat')
```

I have 19 files in a folder that I need to process with this function, but I'm not sure how to parse the filenames and pass them to the function. Something like

```
for filename in folder:
    fixDat(filename)
```

but how do I code `filename` and `folder` in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about [the `os` module's `.walk()` functionality](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm). Where an example would look like:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False): # "." uses current folder
    # change it to a pathway if you want to process files not where your script is located
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

With filename outputs which can be fed to your `fixDat()` function such as:

```
./tmp/test.py
./amrood.tar.gz
./httpd.conf
./www.tar.gz
./mysql.tar.gz
./test.py
```

Note that these are all strings so you could change the script to:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.dat'): # or some other extension
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
            fixDat(os.path.join(root, name))
```